# how to read the json data in multidimensional response

Tags: json, node.js

**How to parse the below data in node** I want to read value by key like special_price =10.0000 & cost=20.0000

```
   [  
   {  
      "attributeCode":"description",
      "value":"<p>The sporty Joust Duffle Bag can't be beat - not in the gym, not on the luggage carousel, not anywhere. Big enough to haul a basketball or soccer ball and some sneakers with plenty of room to spare, it's ideal for athletes with places to go.</p>\r\n<ul>\r\n<li>Dual top handles.</li>\r\n<li>Adjustable shoulder strap.</li>\r\n<li>Full-length zipper.</li>\r\n<li>L 29\" x W 13\" x H 11\".</li>\r\n</ul>"
   },
   {  
      "attributeCode":"special_price",
      "value":"10.0000"
   },
   {  
      "attributeCode":"special_from_date",
      "value":"2016-12-20 00:00:00"
   },
   {  
      "attributeCode":"cost",
      "value":"20.0000"
   },
]
```

Comment: This is not "multidimensional"; it's just an array of objects. It's not JSON; it's just a JS object. You don't want to "parse" the data; you want to **access** it. Also, please spellcheck your post title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to parse to the object

```
var responseArr = [  
   {  
      "attributeCode":"description",
      "value":"<p>The sporty Joust Duffle Bag can't be beat - not in the gym, not on the luggage carousel, not anywhere. Big enough to haul a basketball or soccer ball and some sneakers with plenty of room to spare, it's ideal for athletes with places to go.</p>\r\n<ul>\r\n<li>Dual top handles.</li>\r\n<li>Adjustable shoulder strap.</li>\r\n<li>Full-length zipper.</li>\r\n<li>L 29\" x W 13\" x H 11\".</li>\r\n</ul>"
   },
   {  
      "attributeCode":"special_price",
      "value":"10.0000"
   },
   {  
      "attributeCode":"special_from_date",
      "value":"2016-12-20 00:00:00"
   },
   {  
      "attributeCode":"cost",
      "value":"20.0000"
   },
]

var responseObj = responseArr.reduce(function(obj, elm){
  obj[elm.attributeCode] = elm.value;
  return obj;
}, {})

console.log(responseObj) // Object {description: "<p>The sporty Joust Duffle Bag can't be beat - not…per.</li><li>L 29" x W 13" x H 11".</li></ul>", special_price: "10.0000", special_from_date: "2016-12-20 00:00:00", cost: "20.0000"}
```

then you can `responseObj.special_price` or `responseObj.cost`.
And dont forget to parseFloat.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps you.

```
function parse(data, attribute){
    for(var index in data){
       if(data[index]["attributeCode"] == attribute)
          return data[index]["value"];
    }
    return null;
}
```

e.g.

```
var body=[  
  {  
     "attributeCode":"description",
     "value":"<p>The sporty Joust Duffle Bag can't be beat - not in the gym, not on the luggage carousel, not anywhere. Big enough to haul a basketball or soccer ball and some sneakers with plenty of room to spare, it's ideal for athletes with places to go.</p>\r\n<ul>\r\n<li>Dual top handles.</li>\r\n<li>Adjustable shoulder strap.</li>\r\n<li>Full-length zipper.</li>\r\n<li>L 29\" x W 13\" x H 11\".</li>\r\n</ul>"
  },
  {  
     "attributeCode":"special_price",
     "value":"10.0000"
  },
  {  
     "attributeCode":"special_from_date",
     "value":"2016-12-20 00:00:00"
  },
  {  
     "attributeCode":"cost",
     "value":"20.0000"
  },
];

console.log(parse(body, "special_price"));  //10.000
```